# When I run my procedure to compute the church numeral of an integer, why do I get a #("halt") error?

Tags: algorithm, lambda, functional-programming, scheme, lisp

Alonzo Church used the lambda-calculus to create a system of representing numbers with procedures.

For example: 0 is `x`, 1 is `f x`, 2 is `f(f x)`, and so on where the numeral is how many times `f` is called on `x`.  I wrote a program in Scheme based on prior definitions of zero and add-1 to iteratively compute the Church Numeral of a number.  Code will be put at the end of the post.  I try to run this function on the number 7 and I get an obscure error `Error: <: number required, but got #("halt") [church-numeral, (anon), (anon), (anon), <]`.  The only things that `<` is comparing are numbers, and I can't find anything online anywhere about `#("halt")` other than a [post](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44086) about the error being linguistically incorrect.  What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Code:

```
(define zero (lambda (f) (lambda (x) x)))

(define (add-1 n)
  (lambda (f) (lambda (x) (f ((n f) x)))))

(define one (lambda (f) (f (f x))))

(define (add m n)
  (lambda (f) (lambda (x) ((m f) ((n f) x)))))

(define (church-numeral x)
  (define (iter result x count)
    (if (< count x) 
    (iter (add-1 result x (+ 1 count)))
    count))
  (iter zero x 0))

(church-numeral 7)
```

Comment: Looks like `(iter (add-1 result x (+ 1 count)))` should be `(iter (add-1 result) x (+ 1 count))`. Also, you don't need to pass `x` to `iter`.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat this works, can you put it in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `(iter (add-1 result x (+ 1 count)))` should be `(iter (add-1 result) x (+ 1 count))`.